# Have PHP copy file to local directory automatically on page load

Tags: php

Basically, when a certain page loads, I want to be able to automatically copy a file off a server to a local directory on my computer. This is what I got:

```
<body>
<?php
copy('http://photobooth.josh.com/gsbackgrounds/0001/greenscreen_background.jpg', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BreezeSys\DSLR Remote Pro\PhotoboothImages\greenscreen_background.jpg');
?>
</body>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. If I need to do it on click that would work too, but I'm stuck. The server has PHP5 so I thought this would work?

Comment: That's not going to work unless the server is running on your local machine.  If that's the case, then you have to make sure the server daemon has permissions to write to your target directory.  I think the bigger question is: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah damn. Is there any easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to have a user select what background they want, it downloads to a local machine (mine) as greenscreen_background.jpg and then some software launches that always pulls up greenscreen_background.jpg (so it's always what they picked.)

Comment: dude are you trying to "force" to copy a file from the server to the visitor's computer machine when loading a page oO If that were possible we would be hacked in no time, so the answer is NO unless you find some exploit in your browser ...

Comment: I'm not trying to force anything to anybody's computer but mine.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be installing an FTP server on your computer, then transferring it that way.

Comment: ok, but is the webserver installed on your computer or on a remote computer ?

Comment: Try with a redirect, your browser then will offer to download the file. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Why not just download all the images for backgrounds during installation? Then use CSS to select the appropriate one. Seems a log more simpler.

Comment: My understanding of this is that someone is choosing a picture upon which he will place an effect, through a script on his computer, not his visitor's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off thank you to everyone that tried to resolve my dilemma and sorry for the delayed response.

I found the easiest way to do this was to simply make a javascript function "Copy" and onClick run a batch file/wget-like program on the local machine. It requires Internet Explorer, but that's what we're using.

Anyway I'm only posting our solution for anyone else out there that might run into this same problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to do:

```
// A simple method requiring allow_url_fopen
$file_contents = file_get_contents($resource_url);

// An alternative method requiring cURL
$ch = curl_init($resource_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents($local_file_path, $file_contents);
```

I'm guessing that `copy()` maps to a system call, which doesn't support remote items. There's a chance that modifying the [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) flag might allow it to work, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do fopen.

```
   $contents = file_get_contents('http://****.com/file.jpg');
   $handle =  fopen('yourfilename.jpg',"w");
   fwrite($handle,$contents);
   fclose($handle);
```

Or try curl for dowload.

http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/

```
/**
 * Initialize the cURL session
 */
 $ch = curl_init();

 /**
 * Set the URL of the page or file to download.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ‘http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&topic=t& output=rss’);

 /**
 * Ask cURL to return the contents in a variable instead of simply echoing them to  the browser.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 /**
 * Execute the cURL session
 */
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);

 /**
 * Close cURL session
 */
 curl_close ($ch);
```